# Property 'downloadURL' does not exist on type 'AngularFireUploadTask'

Tags: typescript, angularfire

I have a problem with the line

> this.downloadURL = task.downloadURL()

with AngularFireUploadTask even though I imported it.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from '../../core/auth.service';
    import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference, AngularFireUploadTask } from 'angularfire2/storage';

    import { PostService } from '../post.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-post-dashboard',
      templateUrl: './post-dashboard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./post-dashboard.component.css']
    })
    export class PostDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

      title: string;
      image: string = null;
      content: string;

      buttonText: string = "Create Post"

      uploadPercent: Observable<number>
      downloadURL: Observable<string>

      constructor(
        private auth: AuthService,
        private postService: PostService, 
        private storage: AngularFireStorage
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      uploadImage(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        const path = `posts/${file.name}`
        if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
          return alert('only image files')
        } else {
          const task = this.storage.upload(path, file)

          this.downloadURL = task.downloadURL()

          this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges()
          console.log('Image Uploaded!')
          this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => this.image = url)
        }
      }
```

> The message is:"Property 'downloadURL' does not exist on type
>   'AngularFireUploadTask'.".

What should I do to not have this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
console.log('Image uploaded!');
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
finalize(() => {
  this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL()
  this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => (this.image = url));
})
)
.subscribe();
```

The actual change in code you will need from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rpe8s4-qFFI&t=5415s).

**UPDATE** - 8/30/20

For those of you that want cleaner code, use promises (await in an async function):

```js
const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

// upload image, save url
await task;
console.log('Image uploaded!');
this.image = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
```

Comment: Thank you now now there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The method you want to call is

```
getDownloadURL();
```

Please have a look at this page.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md

Here you can see the the method's signature is

```
getDownloadURL(): Observable<any>
```

Comment: PS: Please note that your code quality is rather poor as long as you omit almost every semicolon at the end of command lines. You should quickly get used to this crucial rule to finish each command with a `;` in order to be recognized as a sophisticated developer.

Comment: it's actually not required to use a semicolon to end a line in JS. You'll find all of your code will execute normally if you remove every one. Many people consider it to be the valid syntax, though most use it still for convention and readability

Answer (score 1):

i got this error while using angular + firebase to upload image,The method `DownloadURL()` doesn't rely on the task anymore, so i will post below how i solved that error

```
upload(event) {
const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(id);
this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);

this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.ref.getDownloadURL() ))
.subscribe();
```

if you want the image source url to anything,you can get it like this,

```
 this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
 finalize(() => {
  this.ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => {
    console.log(url); // <-- do what ever you want with the url..
  });
}))
.subscribe();
```