# Angularfire2 Error "Property 'downloadURL does not exist on type 'AngularFireUploadTask'."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to build upload functionality in my Angular Firebase/Firestore application. I am using this tutorial:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firebase-storage-with-angularfire-dropzone-file-uploader/

And getting this error message from Atom's linter:

`Property 'downloadURL' does not exist on type 'AngularFireUploadTask'.`

The relevant parts from my `file-upload.component.ts` are below. See the code labeled `ERROR HERE`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})

export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {

  // Main Task
  task: AngularFireUploadTask;


  // download URL
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;

  // state for dropzone CSS toggling
  isHovering: boolean;

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  startUpload(event: FileList) {
    //the file object
    const file = event.item(0)

    ...

    // the storage path
    const path = `test/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;

    // The main task
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, {customMetadata})

    // ERROR HERE 
    this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'downloadURL' does not exist on type 'AngularFireUploadTask'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541836/property-downloadurl-does-not-exist-on-type-angularfireuploadtask)

Answer (score 1):

As of Firebase 5.0, there is no longer a downloadUrl on the upload task.  We've mirrored that change in AngularFire. You have to get the url from the ref.

```
import { storage } from 'firebase/storage';

...

const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
this.task = ref.put(file, {customMetadata})

this.downloadURL = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  filter(snap => snap.state === storage.TaskState.SUCCESS)
  switchMap(() => ref.getDownloadURL())
)
```

Comment: So we have to mix AngularFireStorage and firebase storage?